Left a builder's bag of soil outside for a while, now it won't unclump
I had a builder's bag of garden soil (this stuff) delivered and plopped down in my driveway. I was unfortunately called away for work for a short while, so I had to leave it in place there and transfer it to my garden boxes later. During that time, it rained heavily. After shovelling it to the garden boxes, it is now very clumpy, and so far no (manual) attempts have been successful in getting it to a state that would allow for planting vegetables.
It feels like clay, and the stuff that has dried will crumble if I really work it with my hands, but there's obviously way too much to do that. Just under the surface where it's still moist, it's still quite clumpy.
Is there a way that might work to unclump and get it usable? Do I need to top it with a layer of something else? Am I just SOL and need to start over...?


Well...it doesn't -look- like very great soil. If you don't have anything growing in the box yet, if it were me, i'd add a couple bags of compost/manure, and work it in with a cultivator. And just hack at it.

The image you displayed does not look like the product advertised - ie that is not top  mixed with organic matter.   It looks like clay and something which I might find around a drain.   Rain does not turn garden soil/top soil into clay.  I'd start again and check that the top soil you get is high in organic matter.

I'd do a cost analysis. Assuming you are making your normal hourly rate for whatever work you do, is the time spent trying to fix this mess worth more than the time spent to remove it from the planter boxes, buy new soil from a different vendor, and add the new soil to the boxes.  Example: Your hourly rate is $20. You've maybe already spent an hour messing with this, with, let's say, four more hours needed to drive to a store, buy compost ($20 for easy math), and blast apart this mess/mix in compost - so, about $120 vs. removing & replacing it for $50. Go with the cheaper alternative.

Your soil was wetted, dried, and formed into peds.  This is normal.
When the water saturates the soil it separates the particles.  When it dries again, the sand, silt, and clay clump together and eventually become the hard little lumps you're seeing.  You are right, it's far from the uniform soil porosity that gives us good air and water movement. You will also lose a bit of humus and other 'good stuff' that was once in the peds, but not too much in just one rain.
To break them up, you can:

Cultivate the soil - physically bust them apart, with your hands or a soil cultivation tool
Let the earthworms do it - if you cultivate an environment that encourages earthworms (mix in compost!), they will break the peds apart
If you live somewhere with icy winters, the freeze-thaw cycle will bust them up

The force of the raindrop hitting the surface does most of the action. You can prevent it by keeping the soil covered with something - plants or mulch work great, tarps work too.

@stames How'd it work out for you?
